# Count the number of incidents that overlap only no other incidents, 1 other incident, or 2 incidents, etc

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a data set where I need to figure out how many times incidents overlap with each other and get an overall count.

Meaning, how many times did an incident overlap with no other incident, 1 other incident, with 2 incidents, 3 incidents, etc... up to 9 incidents.

My data consists of Column A (Unique ID), Column B (Start date/time m/d/yy h:mm:ss), Column C (Start date/time m/d/yy h:mm:ss), Column D (Duration h:mm:ss)

[image: Data Sample]

**Column E** MAX(SUMPRODUCT(--(callStarts>=C2),--(callStarts<=D2)),SUMPRODUCT(--(callEnds>=C2),--(callEnds<=D2)))+SUMPRODUCT(--(callStartsD2))

**Column F**  SUMPRODUCT(--(C2>=callStarts),--(C2<=callEnds))

The results don't tell me how many times within the data set instances of 0, 1, 2, overlaps as one unit.  It provides the overlap number on each row, thereby skewing my totals.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1501561/edit) to include sample data, expected result and what you have tried so far

Answer (score 0):

The next step would be to take what you have in column E and aggregate it. So add a cell for "no other incident" and use `=COUNTIF(E,"=1")`